# Loading data into CKeditor Angular form

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor and storing the data in the database, now I want to load the data stored in the database to the CKEditor. I am using the editor directly in the form as an element with a selector as ckeditor.

This is the HTML for the editor.

```
    <ckeditor [editor]="Editor" [formControlName]="content"></ckeditor>
```

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
      form.patchValue(res);
}
```

Edit :

```
ngAfterContentChecked() {
    // Working, but it runs ngDoCheck after every change making the field to appear uneditable
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you place a text on the element after angular renders the element then angular will give you a warning that the value has changed after it was rendered.

you can do one of the 2 way:

1. wrap your statement in setTimeout.

   ```
   setTimeout(() => form.patchValue(res));
   ```
2. call detect changes.

   ```
   constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

   ngAfterViewInit() {
       form.patchValue(res);
       this.cdr.detectChanges();
   }
   ```